# Word count for sequence length is wrong

Tags: bash, unix, awk, wc

I have a fasta file that looks like this :

```
>0011 my.header
CAAGTTTATCCACATAATGCGAATAACCAATAATCCTTTTCATAAGTCTATTCTTCATAATCTAAATCGT
TTTCAAGTACATAATTATCCTTTGCCTGTTCGTTAGTTTTATTAAAATTATACTGATCTTTCTTTTTCAT
CCCACGGGTTAAAATCTTCCTCAATCGGTGGGTTTTCTTCATGAAATTGTTTCATTTATTTGCTGTTTTT
AGTTCTCCGATTGTATAACACTTAGTTGTATTAGTGCCGGGTAGTCTATAATTAGCCTCTTTTATATACC
CACGCTTTAATAATCTGTTTACAGAATTATATAATTTGCTCTTAGACATAAAAGGAATAATTTCTCTAAG
TTTAGAAATCGTAATAAAAACGGTATTAGGTTCTTTCTTTACCCTACATCCCTTAAACTTATCCTTATAT
GTATCAGTACAAAGTATAAGAAACATAACTGAATATACTACTGAATCATCTAAACCGATTTCTTTTGCTA
AATCTTCATTTATAACCATAATTATAACGCTTTTAATTGAATTGACTCTTTAACATTTGATGTTTTAACG
AACTGATCGTATATTTCCGGATATTGTTCTTTCAGTGCTTTAGAATCAAGTGATTCACGGCTATACGCTT
TCTTCCTTGTGACTGAAATAAGTTCCCCTTTTATATTATCAGCTTTCGCCTCAGACATCAGACCTAACAA
CTGTTCTTTGAACTTGCCTAAATGTTCGTCTATCTTCTTTTGCATTTCAAGAAGTTCGTAAACGCCTTCT
TCGATATGTGCAACCTTTGCAGGCAACGACTCCAATTTAGCTACATAACTGTCTTTGCTTGCATTGTCTG
CATATCGAACTCCATTCTTACAGCAATTAAGGAATAATTCTATTTCGCTGTCCGGTATGCGTTCAACAGA
GAAAATTCCGTCCTTATCCTTGTCACCTCTTAGCCAAATTGCGATAAGTCCCTCTACTTTCAAATTTGGG
TTTTGTCTCTCGAAAAGATAGGCGTATATTGATAGCTGCCAAGACAAATAAAGCAAATCAAGTTTGTAGG
TAGTTTTAATGTCACCTAAAACGACTGATTTATCAGAGCTGCCCAAATATACTTTATCGGTCGGTGATGC
GATAAGCTCGTTATCAGTTAGAATATACTCAGATGCGATATGAATTAAACCGCTTCCGGCTTTTAAATTC
AAATAGTTCTCTCCGTAGACCGTTTCCGGTTCAATACCTTCTTTGTCGATCCTCTCAACTTCATCATGAA
CCGCTTTCCCTCTCTCAGTTGCCGATCTCAAAATATTATCCGGTATATTGTCAAGTTTGCCTGGAAATAA
```

and I want the length of the sequence (without the header). I tried this:

```
tail -n +2 my.file | wc -c
```

which gives me this output:

```
1349
```

which is wrong, the real size is **1330**.

I'm not sure what's going on. I'm thinking there's probably some sort of hidden characters but I don't know how to explore this.

Comment: The difference between 1330 and 1349 is 19. Your output is 19 lines long. Coincidence?

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but Bash isn't doing any of the counting here.  Shouldn't this be titled "_wc_ word count for sequence is wrong"?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is because `wc` is counting all the line breaks as well.

You may use `awk` to get this done:

```
awk 'NR>1{s+=length()} END{print s}' my.file
```

```
1330
```

---

You may also use `tail | tr | wc`:

```
tail -n +2 my.file | tr -d '\n' | wc -c
1330
```

Answer (score 3):

***EDIT:*** Adding 1 more solution of `awk` here too.

```
awk -v RS="" -v FS="\n" '{$1="";sub(/^ +/,"");gsub(/ /,"");print length($0)}'  Input_file
```

***OR***

```
awk -v RS="" -v FS="\n" '{$1="";sub(/^ +/,"");print length($0)}' OFS=""  Input_file
```

***OR***

```
awk -v RS= '{gsub(/^[^\n]*|\n/, ""); print length()}'  Input_file
```

---

Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk '!/^>/{sum+=length($0)} END{print "Length is:" sum}'  Input_file
```

Comment: You can shorten it to `awk -v RS= '{gsub(/^[^\n]*|\n/, ""); print length()}' file`

Comment: @anubhava, sure thanks sir, added now into solution, cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

perl:

```
perl -0777 -nE 's/^>.*$//m; say tr/A-Z/A-Z/' file
```

That reads the file into a single string, removes the first line, and counts the letters.

Comment: This is really excessively "clever". I voted for anubhava's answer.

Answer (score 2):

bash only, in a script, we have to talk about programming  ;o)

```
tk="$(<my.file)"      # file in variable
tk="${tk#>*$'\n'}"    # suppression header '>...first\n'
tk="${tk//$'\n'}"     # suppression all \n

echo ": ${#tk}"       # 1330  \o/
```

Comment: Double quotes are useless!

Comment: double quotes are useful because, apart from the given example, how to predict the contents of the input file?

Comment: No: when you are assigning something, curly brace will be enough!

Comment: yes, with a simple assignment (with or without curly braces), there is no IFS splitting (in posix, I imagine the same in bash) (but with local, export and some shells, it can be tricky, I believe). So I prefer always show with quotes to learn and to obtain a syntax highlighting more homogeneous. It does not damage performance?

Answer (score 1):

Subtract the line count from the chars after removing the header:

```
tail -n +2  fasta.file | wc -lc | awk '{print $2-$1}'
```